# Indirect cast from int to int *

Tags: c, casting

Can someone explain me why I cannot do this?

```
int *ptr;
int ival;
ptr = ival;
*ptr = 255;
```

When I do the same with `double` and `int` values instead of `int` and `int *` values I will just have an indirekt cast, why can't it work for the last pair?

Comment: You're trying to assign an `int` to a pointer.  If you want `ptr` to point at `ival`, you would need `ptr = &ival;`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "indirect cast".  The reason this doesn't work is you're trying to assign an `int` to an `int *`, which generally doesn't make sense.  If you want to force it to happen, you need to cast the `int` to `int *` before making the assignment.  But normally you would take the address of the `int`, obtaining an `int *`, then assign that to the pointer.

Comment: `ptr = ival;` eh ... do you mean this? As it stands you're assigning some (uninitialised, hello UB) integer value as address of a pointer. That's not how pointer arithmetic is supposed to be done.

Comment: If I have `double d = 2.0; int i = d;` It works, why It shouldnt work for `int`and `int *`?

Comment: "Can someone explain me why I cannot do this?" - Because it is undefined behaviour? Beacuse it is nonsense? What do you **think** it does? What do you want to accomplish? Why do you think it should do anything useful? It is not a bit better with `double`, btw. There is a reason a modern compiler warns about this (if not: enable warnings as you **always** should)

Comment: I don't think it is usefull, I just would like to understand why it doesn't work. One could argue that you can find out the adress and just copy it in an integer and asign it like that. so I can write an address like 228045 or something as an integer and it will be seen as an `int *` like the example with int and double.

Comment: `I just would like to understand why it doesn't work.` Then you need to read more about the difference between `int` and `int*`

Comment: Just read the standard. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: I see you don't want int ival, *ptr=&ival; as most others sensibly assumed. Then TomKarzes's comment above and bta's answer below are indeed what you're looking for. Just write int ival=1234, *ptr=(int *)ival; But now, executing that *ptr=255 statement is almost certain to segfault. As I've written it, with ival=1234 initialized, *ptr=255 tries to store the value 255 at the (likely sizeof(int)=4) bytes at absolute physical address 1234, which is likely not in your address space. To execute *ptr=255, you'd **have** to want ptr=&ival, and **not** ptr=(int *)ival.

Comment: @JohnForkosh: The C standard does not even mention "segmentation fault". It is just undefined behaviour. Another problem is the conversion of an `int` to a pointer type is not guaranteed to yield any reasonable result either (and on typical 64 bit systems it very likely will not). Anyway, it is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
ptr = ival;
```

it means you want to copy the **value** of `ival` to the value of `ptr`. If you want `ptr` to point to the location where `ival` is stored, you have to use the address-of operator `&`:

```
ptr = &ival;
```

I suspect you may be confused because you don't need to do this when the right-hand side of the assignment is an array, e.g. you can write.

```
char *ptr;
char cvar[10];
ptr = cvar;
```

That's a special case becaue arrays can't be assigned as values in C, and when you try to use them in that context they automatically decay to a pointer to their first element. So the last line is treated as if you'd written:

```
ptr = &cvar[0];
```

This special behavior only happens for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here?  If you're wanting to store a pointer to the variable `ival`, then you need to use `ptr = &ival;`.  If you want to use the numerical value stored in `ival` as a memory address and set the pointer to that, then you need to do `ptr = (int*)ival;`.

The reason you can't do `ptr = ival;` is because the compiler - like those of us reading the question - can't tell which of these two things you're trying to do.  Never make the compiler figure out what you mean; always be explicit.

You can do this with a `double` and an `int` because the language defines procedures for converting between numeric data types.  The language specifically does *not* define procedures for converting between numeric types and pointer types.  Different platforms can have different ways of formatting pointers, and there's no guarantee that it's even *possible* to represent a pointer as a numeric value (this was more of a problem when C was first standardized than it is today).  When you add the manual typecast, you're telling the compiler that you know what you're doing and that it's safe to attempt to make a conversion that it wouldn't try to do on its own.